# android:pitfalls of deleting ldpi/mdpi folders

Tags: android-layout, android

I was wondering what are the pitfalls of deleting the ldpi/mdpi/hdpi folders on my android project? Can i just copy all the images in the drawable folder instead?

I did see the following links about UI development for android
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

thanks

PS: I 'm referring to all the images that are being used, background,icons,menus etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to, go for it. Although not the best practice, if your application is quite conservative in terms of graphics then this may be a reasonable approach.

**PROS:**

- Smaller .apk size
- Easier to manage images (add/edit/remove)

**CONS:**

- Images may be too high res or too low res for different screen resolutions.
- If too high, images are scaled down on the fly which eats up processing power (+ unnecessary memory consumption).
- If too low, images will lack detail and may look bad.
- Lower-end devices have a lower memory cap (lowest being 16MB I think) - what may seem to work on your test device may not work on another (OutOfMemoryError!).

**Update**

If you want a quick way to make icons for all resolutions check out: [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)

Comment: There is something I don’t understand. In the icon design document they say that (for example) mdpi laucher icons should be of size 48 × 48. But if you take two mdpi screens, they will not necessarily have exactly the same resolution, mdpi is just an indication. Does the icon will nevertheless be displayed at size 48 × 48, no matter what the actual resolution of the screen is?

Comment: @Che:I agree that is definitely a problem in terms of images looking incorrect. So are nine patch images the only way to go..by that i mean if i have a nine patch image which is of mdpi ..would that be ok?

Comment: between those two mdpi screens, both will display icons at 48x48

Comment: If you can pull it off, sure. But nine patch images are generally quite simple and used for stretchable backgrounds/borders. If you really want to you could keep one icon at high res (may not look right as well at low res). Best practice is to have different icons for different resolutions.

Comment: @Che What about sprites in a game which will anyway be scaled to the correct size? Are there any reasons to have several versions of these images (vs. one high resolution version)?

Comment: Of course, lower resolution screens generally exist on devices with weaker hardware specs, any less scaling (scale downs) = increased performance

Comment: What would happen to layouts ...do those also need to be tweaked to make it work correctly on multiple devices

Comment: You'll have to find that out through testing. From experience with Honeycomb tablets, layouts have to be drastically different due to the large amount of screen estate suddenly available.