# Android: Designing Different Icons for Screen Densities

Tags: android

I know it's good practice to design different menu icons for different screen densities. I read that the preferred size for the different densities are:

- 36 X 36 px for low
- 48 x 48 px for medium
- 72 X 72 px for high

I want to avoid doing unnecessary work. Is it a good idea to design just 1 icon at 72 X 72 px, and just use that, and have Android do the resizing automatically? I don't see how that's any different than me resizing it and creating 3 separate images?

Comment: Question is similar to one I answered recently: [http://stackoverflow.com/q/6682038/828060](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6682038/828060)

Comment: If you do automatic resizing, image quality drops sharply and icon may not look good. Also I don't think Android will do resizing for you (I may be wrong here).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The benefit of having different icons is that **you** have control over the final appearance, rather than allowing an algorithm to munge your image. Few scaling algorithms are able to maintain quality when reducing an image's dimensions, especially for complex icons.

Be sure to read [Android's scaling rules](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#scaling), and also [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/) has an excellent investigation into image scaling and its effects on the final image.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the link. However, if I were to design different icons, I'd simply take a very large image and scale them both down to the appropriate sizes.. wouldn't this be exactly what Android do too? So I'm thinking I don't need to do it myself

Comment: Right, that's what most people would do. The benefit is, if the act of scaling makes the image look like hammered dung you can fix it. The drawback is, if you include images for each version you're going to increase your package size a bit.